# Add data to the CKEditor jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

Hi I am using this ajax to post and get data ,After that I want to append data back to the CKEDITOR

Please let me know where is the error ?

```js
$(".ddlPredefinedTemplate").change(function() {
  var ddlPredefinedTemplate = $("[id*=ddlPredefinedTemplate]");
  var selectedText = ddlPredefinedTemplate.find("option:selected").text();
  var selectedValue = ddlPredefinedTemplate.val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "BenchCompanyEmail.aspx/PredefinedTemplate_Select",
    data: '{Value: "' + selectedValue + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {


      CKEDITOR.instances['txtTemplate'].setData(data.d)

    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPredefinedTemplate" TabIndex="3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control ddlPredefinedTemplate">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>

                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                        <label>
                                            <span style="color: Red">*&nbsp;</span>Template Subject :
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" placeholder="Template Subject" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="form-control txtSubject"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 topmg">
                                        <label>
                                            <span style="color: Red">*&nbsp;</span>Template : 
                                        </label>
                                        <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtTemplate" TabIndex="5" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="200px"
                                            BasePath="../ckeditor"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
```

I am facing this error:

> Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

Comment: Do a `console.log(data);` **before** that line with `setData` in it, and let us know what you see in the console.

Comment: **`CKEDITOR.instances['txtTemplate']`** is undefined.

Comment: data=[object Object]  this is result of console.log(data);

Comment: What is `txtTemplate`?

Comment: result of console.log(data.d) 

<p>
 Hello {Vendor FirstName}</p>
<p>
 Greetings from Luminous Tec.</p>
<p>
 Kindly add my Email Id: <a href="mailto:gracy@luminoustec.com">gracy@luminoustec.com</a> to your distribution list and share your requirements on daily basis so that I can help you out with a good resource.</p>
<p>

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez this is id for the ckeditor text area

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez u there ?

Comment: Yes, Can you post your code in https://jsfiddle.net/? I'd like to see and debug the issue.

Comment: Sir I have asp.net code as well , I cant Jsfiddle that

Comment: Can you post the ASPX HTML part in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145224/discussion-between-serious-coder-and-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using MasterPage change:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['txtTemplate'];
```

to

```
CKEDITOR.instances['ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTemplate'];
```

Why?

Since ASP.NET dynamically processes the IDs of controls, then on the client side, through JavaScript you can only access the context of dynamically generated controls with client id.

Hope this helps.